# How can I create a variable with different names depending on the number of an iteration in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

Hello I am trying to create a for loop where a variable is created depending on the value of a column that only has 10 possible values. Ideally the for loop goes and filters the data using dplr by the number and then rewrites the variable sliced for only the first 15 observations.

```
I created the following but it doesn’t work 
for (i in 1:10){
mvendidos[[i]] <-           filter(dff,grupo==i)
mvendidos[[i]] <- slice(dff.1:15)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the type of `i`. Add `%>% as.character()` and do not forget to create the "container" `list`:

```
mvendidos <- list()
for (i in 1:10){
mvendidos[[i %>% as.character()]] <- filter(dff,grupo==i)
# mvendidos[[i %>% as.character()]] <- slice(dff.1:15) # Commented as the synthax is doubtful
}
```

By the way. I doubt that `dff.1:15` is correct. But it is not a part of your question and the structure of `dff` is not available.

**Appended**

I think I need to attract your attention to the operator `%>%`. You can read about `dplyr` [pipes here](https://style.tidyverse.org/pipes.html).

In this case you can replace it with base R 4.2+ operator `|>`as well.

Comment: @KingP I have appende my answer as it could be misunderstood